# Docker: How to access to a private github repo using ssh?

Tags: git, github, ssh, private, docker

I'm trying to clone a private repo from github using Docker. The problem is that I need to use ssh to access to that repo. I added a key in my github project's setting which is used, I suppose, to identify the docker's server.

My problem is that I can't figure out what I should write in my Dockerfile so that the server use that key when it tries to access to my github repo. I saw examples where id_rsa is added to the container, but I don't know where id_rsa is stored on their server, if it exists

```
RUN mkdir /root/.ssh/
# can't find the file id_rsa
ADD id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa 
RUN touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN ssh-keyscan github.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts

run git clone git@github.com:user/repo.git
```

How do I access to my private repo from docker's server ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use `git` from the Dockerfile, you need to configure the container in the same way as you would configure your own development machine.

I can't really understand which is "their" in "their server", so I'm just guessing.

When you registered a public key with github, you should have got the private key too. That's the `id_rsa` that you see in other examples.

If you can not locate that file, just start over. Delete the old key, [generate a new one](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) and configure it on github and on your docker build context (in your example, just copy it in the same folder as the Dockerfile).

As a different strategy, you might want to do the checkout outside of the image build process (clone locally and `ADD` everything to the image).

Comment: I didn't know about the building context, I thought ADD searched the file on the host directly, that's also the reason why I used git clone in the Dockerfile which was useless since, as you said, I just had to add the directory where the Dockerfile was located. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

I managed to do this by using ssh-add on the key.

A "problem" with using multiple `RUN` instructions is that non-persistent data won't be available at the next `RUN`. I managed to log in and use github private repos with

```
RUN eval `ssh-agent -s` && \
    ssh-add id_rsa && \
    git clone git@github.com:user/repo.git
```

By using the `&&`'s on a single CMD, the `eval` process will still be running and ssh-agent has the key loaded when you connect to github.

I hope this helps.

Comment: As I said, I don't know where id_rsa is on their server, the problem isn't building on my computer, it's building on their server

Comment: If you use `ADD` it should be the same path as the `Dockerfile`

Comment: I believe doing it in this manner will include your `id_rsa` key within your docker cache until you remove them. I realize the OP is showing this as well but it might not be a good idea to add your id_rsa key to a docker container nonetheless.